# I'm having trouble with a variable 'v' inside of nested for loops not returning correctly when called outside of the loops

Tags: python, variables

```
    for player in game:
        v = 0
        de = 0
        opponents = []
        opponents = game[player]['K']
        for people in opponents:
            v = v + v_one(c_mu(players[player][0]), c_mu(players[people][0]), c_phi(players[people][1]))
            1#print v
        2#print v
```

When I ask for v to be returned at position 1, it gives the expected values given the number I give the v_once function (all real numbers, all float, and no 0s), and 8 of them, which is the number I expected:

0.111910751103
0.223821502205
0.111802412635
0.102979014673
0.206305689094
0.309632363515
0.109644988552
0.219289977104

When I try to print 'v' at position 2 however it gives 6 values, and the last two are just 0:

0.223819721884
0.111791745003
0.307795544547
0.219115319988
0
0

I'm pretty lost here and am not sure what could be the cause. As I said above There are no inputs that would give a 0 return value, so I think it has something to do with defining v within a for loop?

Comment: Where do you define the variable game?

Comment: Could you please properly format your code? At the moment it is not clear whether "position 2" is inside or outside the `for player in game` loop.

Comment: Sorry the formatting was off, it didn't come out cleanly.

Comment: And game is a dictionary, so it should be iterating through all the key names which are; PlayerA, PlayerB, etc

Comment: Is it possible there are no opponents for the last two players?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Woodham I was so preoccupied with the v that I forgot that the way I'd implemented the algorithm the result can be 0 if it isn't combined with the other parts... which I haven't written yet.

Answer (score 0):

this was a very specific case and I doubt that anybody will find this useful, but here it is.
Because of how I was implementing the algorithm I am using, it is possible to get a 0 from the algorithm if you don't combine the 3 parts, the other two of which I hadn't written yet... so yeah, entirely my fault.
Thanks to everybody who left a reply, it helped get me digging back into things that I had thought were finished.
Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks again.